# What to do when codedui does not recognize anything below a tree

Tags: treeview, coded-ui-tests

I want to automasize a winform application which includes a custom tree implementation, codedui recognizes only the tree but does not recognize anything below the tree and even does not click points on the tree it recognized..
(I am also open to advices why recorded points on tree not clicked when played ?)

Here is structure of the tree, all nodes has one level subnode

```
 Node 1
   Sub Node 1a
   Sub Node 1b
   Sub Node 1c
   ...
 Node 2
   Sub Node 2a
   Sub Node 2b
   Sub Node 2c
   ...
 Node ...
```

So, I tried to click tree nodes programmatically. I tried to get nodes by name but didnt worked and tried to get nodes 0 of node 0 as below but getting error

```
   WinTree uITVTree = this.UIProMANAGEWindow.UIReportsWindow.UITVWindow.UITVTree;

        uITVTree.DrawHighlight();

        TreeNode treeNode = uITVTree.Nodes[0].Nodes[0];
```

and I am getting below warning in IDE

UITestControl does not contain for 'Nodes' and no accessible extension method 'Nodes' accepting a first argument of type 'UITestControl' could be found

I wonder if there is a solution that clicks nodes in order regardles of the names , for example click first subNode of Node 1 ?

Below code only runs 2 times in foreach loop and It works so slow and I couldnt get meaningul strings in messega box. I dont know how I can click individual nodes in the code even if I ever get them in foreach loop. In below statement setProperty doesnt work. (it does give error but nothing changes on the screen)

```
        UITestControlCollection childNodes = uITVTree.Nodes;
        foreach (UITestControlnode in childNodes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(node.ToString());
            node.SetProperty(WinTreeItem.PropertyNames.Selected, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom controls need to be made accessible to be usable in Coded UI Tests.
You will need to expose certain properties (control name, coordinates, etc...) from your custom control so your coded UI test can work with it.
Study [this](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/enabling-automation-by-adding-accessibility-to-windows-forms-controls/) example from Ranorex, it should give you some insights on how to achieve this for winform controls.
[Another](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2011/10/28/coded-ui-test-extension-for-3rd-party-windows-forms-controlshow-to/) resource that could be useful.

A explanation for the coordinates not being clicked could be that the control is blocked by another control.

Comment: I used Ranorex before but  not in too detailed. so you mean I need to write that custom tree again ? or you mean I ony need to write some plugin ? Can you tell how can I do ? Issue ıs eventually plugıns click on coordinates right ? But here it doesnt click on coordinates properly. I am OK if it brokes test, I am ready to handle resolution changes or some control place changes but now nothing changes and still not clicking properly..I dont understand why people saying same thing over and over again, I know screen and control changes things, those are basic things, here is problem is different.

Comment: I never needed to implement accessibility for winform controls, so I'm afraid I can't help you more than I already did. I suggest setting up a test project containing that custom control and start experimenting that way.

Comment: Actually you did not give me a real answer but I still accepted it as answer because there is no other answer.